# visual studio 2012 is not recognizing changes in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, debugging

For some reason, visual studio (2012) is not reading any changes in my code. It will recognize an error but, for example, if I get rid of something that makes a window appear, a window will still appear. I am also unable to debug my code (I get the 'symbols not loaded for this document' error). This has been going on for a few days.

I'm not quite sure what to do. I've cleared the visual studio cache but that didn't help. I've   changed the startup project settings around but that doesn't change anything either. This is all from my local machine (no source/version control). Does anyone know why this is?

**I fixed this by deleting the .suo (silverlight user options) file, as was suggested in the link below, thanks @amalgamate**

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/08/why-visual-studio-debugger-is-not.html

Comment: Try this simple fix, might be a solution to your problem.
[Configurations Manager projects unchecked][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726034/visual-studio-2012-not-detecting-file-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be your answer and I do not know silver light, but I have found the symbols not loaded error often when the solution file lost track of where a project file was, or when a project file lost track of a library. Maybe the file is missing, or maybe someone else on your team directed it else where etc.. To fix this in project explorer, right click on the solution or project and re-add the particular reference or project (using the add menu item). You may then have to remove the old project/ or reference. You will know the references and projects are bad because of the icon next to them in the project explorer. The bad links will also be listed in the output of your build with the bad links named.

Comment: I've re-added the project references several times - to no avail

Comment: Perhaps they are references to .NET files that are not found. Are you building against the correct version? You can adjust this in properties under the application tab under the field "Target Framework". Do you have more than one .NET framework installed?

Comment: I've only got 4.5 on my machine, and the target framework is 4.5

Comment: Ok I think that I was/am off track there, If the debugging is not linking check properties under debug and select "Enable unmanaged code debugging". Assuming there is some unmanaged code.

Comment: Where can I do this? There's no option to do so in the projects settings

Comment: Perhaps try an opposite track, try adding something, a message box write line whatever to prove that the change does not get put in Just to be sure it's doing what you think if you cant step through the debugging.

Comment: there are tabs on the left of the project settings: application, build, build events, debug, etc. select debug.

Comment: I have done that several times, nothing I add changes, I have cleared out entire functions and it still works, provided the function is there.

Comment: Sounds like the project in question is not getting built.

Comment: Yeah that's my assumption but I have no idea why

Comment: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/08/why-visual-studio-debugger-is-not.html shows that in 2012 (I'm in 2010) select web>debuggers>silverlight. It has some other solutions that you might try as well.

Comment: If there is more than one project in the solution, try building each project one at a time. You view that output from the build and it says:?

Comment: Holy crap - it's fixed! Now on to my other issue of why the heck it wont make service references correctly! Thank you so much man!

Comment: Glad to help even if I really was pretty clueless there.

Comment: btw: the link shows that @justnS was a good first step so Plus one to him, yes.

Comment: Also, clearly my answer is crap, when looked at as a whole. You could write your own answer as an answer and select as correct, and I'll delete my less than perfect post. There's no points in it, but who cares about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try Build > Clean Solution then Build

Comment: Nope - still acting like I haven't made any changes

Comment: This has been going on for a few days, visual studio has been restarted several times - as has my computer

Comment: @user2084666 try deleting your bin folder and moving your entire solution to another directory. If that doesn't work then I'm going to call shenanigans!