# Visual Studio 2012 not detecting file changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Just recently after I had made some changes to configurations of my solution and project Visual Studio 2012 stopped recognizing my changes and therefore does not build my changes when I select build.  I now have to select rebuild every time I want to build my project.  Even clicking start debugger does not detect that the project and solution is out of date.  After I make changes to a file and save it, if the project has already been build this is the total output from build:

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Usually VS will iterate each project and output that it doesn't need to be built for this or that reason.  Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

This is the result of a rebuild operation.  Project names and other sensitive information have been replaced with *'s.

http://pastebin.com/FiGqZpui

Comment: What does Rebuild Solution output?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and discovered the problem - I had unchecked my project's build checkbox in the solution's build configuration manager.

To check or fix this, right click on your solution, select "Configuration Manager", and then select the "build" checkbox for your project.  This will make it so any changes to files in your project will force a rebuild when you run the application or just choose to build.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what my issue was.... but I fixed it.  That may have been it, but it's been so long now I can't be certain.  Though I have had that problem and solution at least once before so I'll +1.